# Price calculator for woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce, calculator, price

can someone tell me is there a plugin for this cost calculator for woocommerce. And if there isn't how to connect whit the woocommerce plug in. This is the example that I'm looking for https://z3ddota.com/dota2-mmr-boosting/.

Answer (score 0):

Same functionality is not available in WooCommerce any plugin.We can implement same functionality with custom plugin.So please share your requirement.